# Will it happen - object created and immediately garbage collected in java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Is there a slightest chance that an object is created and before it is assigned to a reference variable will get eligible for garbage collection.

According to the [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html) there are 4 phases in Marking, and last phase `Final Marking phase` runs by keeping the java threads paused. Now there is a chance of a thread created an object and paused by the `Final Marking phase` before assigning it to a reference variable. Now in this phase it identified the object as live object and should be eligible for GC.

**what happens  :**

1. If the object is GCed, the thread which created it, will not have
   the created object after it resumes.
2. If the object is not GCed,
       what makes it to escape being identified as orphan object.

Comment: I really doubt it.  The JVM designers would have thought of this.

Comment: Using a simplistic description of an **extremely** complex process then attempting to diagnose thread safety issues in it is like assessing the viability of the US space program by examining the [blueprints of the Up Goer 5](https://xkcd.com/1133/). This is an exercise in futility and a waste of your time.

Comment: This is why I initialize my objects with: `Object o = null; while(o == null) o = new Object();` </joke>

Comment: Created but not assigned objects are referenced by the stack.  They are not GCed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a slightest chance

For sufficiently buggy implementations, sufficiently reckless developers bypassing VM verification/safety nets or [invocations of C-x M-c M-butterfly](https://xkcd.com/378/): Yes, of course.

On the other hand, in a perfect system behaving and being used according to spec GCs are only allowed to happen at well-defined, consistent execution states.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is like

```
a = new A();
```

was executed as

```
    new A();
a =
```

So an object gets created, then the `a` sees the equals sign and looks for the something to be assigned. This could never work as for the assignment, you must be able to get the RHS, i.e., the object must already be stored somewhere. In case of bytecode, this somewhere is the stack and all the thread stacks are GC roots.